# Load HTML file to WebView with custom CSS

Tags: java, html, android, css, webview

I have a WebView on my Android application which loads (`WebView.loadUrl()`) different local HTML files from phone's internal storage. I would like to include some custom css styles for them.

Now, I could have my app edit every HTML file and add linking reference for the CSS file.

I could also read the file contents, add the CSS linking and use `WebView.loadData()` to load it.

But is it possible to do this a lot simpler and efficiently?

**Note:** The HTML files are downloaded from a website. So editing them manually is not possible in this case, but once downloaded they can be edited via the app if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility (I have not tried this):

[WebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(String baseUrl, String data, ..)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

takes a `baseURL` for the document to use to resolve relative URLs. Take a look at the CSS url and construct `baseURL` so that CSS url will reference local CSS file.