# WebView, add local .CSS file to an HTML page?

Tags: android, html, css, resources, httpclient

In android I'm using WebView to display a part of a webpage which I fetched from the internet using HttpClient from Apache. To only have the part I want from the html, I use Jsoup.

```
String htmlString = EntityUtils.toString(entity4); // full html as a string                                 
Document htmlDoc = Jsoup.parse(htmlString); // .. as a Jsoup Document
Elements tables = htmlDoc.getElementsByTag("table"); //important part
```

Now I can just load `tables.toString()` in the WebView and it displays. Now I want to link a CSS file which I store inside my assets folder with this page. I know I can have something like

```
<LINK href="styles/file.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

In my html, but how do I link it so that it uses the one I've stored locally?

---EDIT---
I've now changed to this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("<HTML><HEAD><LINK href=\"file:///android_asset/htmlstyles_default.css\" type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\"/></HEAD><body>");
    sb.append(tables.toString());
    sb.append("</body></HTML>");
    return sb.toString();
```

Somehow I do not get the styles applied to the page. Is it the location path I used that is wrong?

Comment: If you make a request to get a webpage, css file is not downloaded, you must specify your own by changing the location of the table style

Comment: I know that, I have made one already ;)

Comment: So now you must store this file in your application(file, variable, ..) and change the path of the link.href using same jsoup

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Seva Alekseyev is right, you should store CSS files in `assets` folder, but referring by `file:///android_asset/filename.css` URL doesn't working for me.

There is another solution: put CSS in `assets` folder, do your manipulation with HTML, but **refer to CSS by relative path**, and load HTML to WebView by [`loadDataWithBaseURL()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", htmlString, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

E.g. you have `styles.css` file, put it to `assets` folder, create HTML and load it:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("<HTML><HEAD><LINK href=\"styles.css\" type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\"/></HEAD><body>");
sb.append(tables.toString());
sb.append("</body></HTML>");
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", sb.toString(), "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

P.S. I've come to this solution thanks to [Peter Knego's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114496/load-html-file-to-webview-with-custom-css/4114753#4114753).

Comment: Is it possible to do this with an html file in the assets folder?  So far, it looks like it's just using the data field for the html file and I don't have it stored in a variable.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot store arbitrary files in `res` - just the specific resource types (drawables, layouts, etc.). The CSS should go to the `assets` folder instead. Then you can refer to it by the following URL: `file:///android_asset/MyStyle.css`

Comment: Your HTML is grossly malformed - you need `<html><head>` in the beginning, and also `</body></html>` at the end, not another `<body>`.

Comment: You can store arbitrary files in res/raw.

Answer (score 0):

There are several steps: **Android Studio**

1- Make sure copy the HTML and CSS file in Asset folder

2- Add link to html file like this:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="file:///android_asset/myStyle.css">
```

3- As usual manage the CSS file
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
}

```
    th, td {
        text-align: right;
        padding: 8px;
        font-family: "my_font";
    }

    tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #BCA37F;

    }
    tr:nth-child(odd) {
        background-color: #EAD7BB;

    }
```

4- Even it is possible to set a Font for each html file :

```
 <style>
        @font-face {font-family: 'my_font';src: url('file:///android_asset/nazanin.ttf');}


    </style>
```

5- Finally , for Webview Just use `webview.loadUrl`

```
wvInfo.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/htmlFile.html")
```

Answer (score -1):

On a related note, if you're *not* storing the file in the assets folder and want to use relative paths, Webview on Android sometimes requires dot-slash before relative paths.

```
<LINK href="./styles/file.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

See [this post](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/3851/webview-on-android-and-local-css-files)