# Change user agent of Internet Explorer in Windows Phone 8.1 while navigating to local html content

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, webview, httprequest, mathjax

In a Windows Phone 8.1 app I've a `WebView` that renders some local html pages. By default the `WebView` acts like an Internet Explorer in **mobile mode**. But Internet Explorer mobile mode has some restriction: can't render `MathJax`. So I need to change the user agent.

So far I've found two methods to change the user agent:

1. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25228722/change-user-agent-in-wp8-1-webview/25229068#25229068)  is explained how to change user agent, but this creates Certification error while publishing the app in windows store, windows store does not allow `urlmon.dll`
2. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28555117/1067326) is explained how to change the user agent with [HttpWebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.httprequestmessage.aspx). But I can't implement this for loading local html files.

My question is how can I implement the second method to load local html files?

Comment: It sounds like you are really encountering this MathJax bug: https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/1085 See the issue thread for a workaround; this will be fixed in the next release.

Comment: I'm still seeing that bug in a scenario where I prejax the html and ship the jaxed html with my app.