# android webview loadUrl with custom font

Tags: android, css, webview, font-size

My webview charge viewing a page from a server

```
private String url = "http://192.168.33.37/gestpresenze/index.html";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);
    //carichiamo la webview dentro il layout specificato
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);


    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    mWebView.loadUrl(url);
}
```

Is it possible that user view this page with a font determined not by the CSS of the page on the server but from a font of the app?

For example, the method `setDefaultFixedFontSize` sect font established or that of the CSS of the page loaded ?

Comment: Here is the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900658/how-to-change-font-face-of-webview-in-android

Comment: no,the page that i load is on the sever,not in local

Answer (score 0):

Look here [Rendering HTML in a WebView with custom CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950729/rendering-html-in-a-webview-with-custom-css) , you have to retrieve the html and modify with a custom css. You have to do a kind of merge with the other post.

Comment: this seems to me the best solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30018540/inject-css-to-a-site-with-webview-in-android