# Injecting css for Webview with custom font

Tags: android, html, css, webview

I have working with webview in which i want to inject css to webview that i have achieved with the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30018540/inject-css-to-a-site-with-webview-in-android).

But if i want to add custom font to css i have using the following code

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'avenir_next'; /*a name to be used later*/
    src: url('OTF_FILE_LINK'); /*URL to font*/
}

body {
    font-family: avenir_next;
}
```

I need to know that its is possible to load otf file from the Android Asset folder insted of using 'OTF_FILE_LINK'.

Comment: did you find the solution? I m working on it.

Comment: for a workaround i load the otf file from the server link