# Is it possible to style div classes in Android TextView or Webview?

Tags: android, webview, textview

I fetched and succesfully showed HTML data from a server in a TextView. The data is written like this:

```html
<div class=head1>
  Head 1
</div>

<div class=head2>
  Head 2
</div>
```

My question is, is it possible to give the different div classes a color and show it into a WebView or TextView? I am not able to change the data because I don't own it.

Comment: Yes, it is possible - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30018540/inject-css-to-a-site-with-webview-in-android

Comment: It's working ty.