# load font family from Assests into WebView dinamically

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview, android-webview

I have some `ttf` files in `assets` directory of my application, for example `AdobeArabic-Regular.ttf`. Now I want to run this `javascript` code in `WebView`:

```
object.style.fontFamily = "AdobeArabic-Regular";
```

But I do not know how I can load that font dynamically? As `font family` will be changed dinamically, using [this described way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7395170/1043882) does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inject CSS into webview this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30018910/11480111) is helpful

And set the font in CSS

```
body {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
```