# Why doesn't WebView support direct CSS injection?

Tags: java, android, css, webview, inject

I know the fact that I can inject CSS using JavaScript DOM manipulation in WebView. But, I am curious about the fact that direct injection is not available. Is there a technical reason for this.?

Comment: you can use Javascript to manipulate page dom, here is solution 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30018540/inject-css-to-a-site-with-webview-in-android

Comment: I already know that. My question is not the solution to this problem. But a reason, why things work a certain way and not in a certain way.