# WebView deoesn't open links neither in browser nor in the App

Tags: android, webview

This is my WebView code :

```
String mimeType = "text/html";
String encoding = "utf-8";
String htmlText = itemJob.getJobDesc();

String text = "<html><head>"
        + "<style type=\"text/css\">@font-face {font-family: MyFont;src: url(\"file:///android_asset/fonts/custom.otf\")}body{font-family: MyFont;color: #0b0b0b;text-align:left;font-size:15px;margin-left:0px}"
        + "</style></head>"
        + "<body>"
        + htmlText
        + "</body></html>";
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, text, mimeType, encoding, null);
```

When I click on Links inside the WebView, nothing happens! How to open links in the Browser?

Comment: I think you should refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30018540/inject-css-to-a-site-with-webview-in-android

Comment: What API are you targeting?

Comment: from android 4.0 to latest

Answer (score 0):

use this.. it is perfectly worked for me.

Hopefully this is working for you

```
wvDesciption.loadData("<p align='justify'>" + mCouresubModel.getDescription() + "</p>", "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
```